# First rocket equation (sign before $dm$)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conventions, rocket-science

I'm trying to understand the first rocket equation. At start it says:
$$P(t+dt)-P(t)=dP$$
$$((m+dm)(v+dv)-dm(v+dv+v_r))-mv=Fdt$$
I understand why there is minus before $dm$ at the second part but what I don't understand is why there is no minus before $dm$ in $m+dm$.
How can mass of the rocket increase when the rocket is consuming fuel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dm is defined to be the infintesimal change in the rocket's mass. In math:
$$
dm = m(t+dt)-m(t)
$$
If the rocket is consuming fuel, dm is negative. If the rocket was somehow spontaneously creating fuel, dm would be positive. In either case, the mass after time $dt$ is $m+dm$. It's never $m-dm$. The minus sign is absorbed in the $dm$.

In general, dx is just the change in x. dx can be positive or negative. You don't *explicitly* put in the sign, because it's *implicit* in the definition of dx.

If you like, you could simplify the expression you wrote above and solve for $dm$. Once you do this, you'll see explicitly that $dm$ is negative, just like you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

I think another approach to the rocket equation is better. We assume that we have a rocket that is moving with momentum $p~=~mv$. This rocket ejects a small increment of mass $\Delta m$ at velocity $-V$ relative to the rocket or $-V~+~v$ to the lab frame. The rocket mass is reduced to $m~-~\Delta m$ and its velocity increases to $v~+~\Delta v$ as a result the total momentum conserved is
$$
mv~=~(m~-~\Delta m)(v~+~\Delta v)~-~(V~-~v)\Delta m.
$$
Now do the mathematics and ignore the $\Delta m\Delta v$ term as negligible so
$$
m\Delta v~=~-V\Delta m.
$$
Now divide the m and integrated
$$
\int_{v_i}^{v_f}dv~=~v_f~-~v_i~=~-V\int_{m_i}^{m_f}\frac{dm}{m} = V~ln\left(\frac{m_i}{m_f}\right).
$$
This is why if a rocket puts $10\%$ of its mass in orbit that it reaches terminal velocity $2.3V$, where $V$ is the velocity of the gas escaping the rocket. A top chemical rocket has a specific impulse $isp~=~v/g$ $=~550s$ for $g~=~9.8m/s^2$ This means the plume velocity is $5400m/s$ and so the terminal velocity is $12400m/s$.